# "Before you can submit for review, complete the following" received during Facebook app approval

Tags: facebook

We are trying to get our app accepted but we cannot figure out how to submit notes for the 2 remaining issues mentioned regarding **Taggable Friends** and app verification. Getting error below but I don't understand where to update.

> **Before you can submit for review, complete the following:**
>   Please provide a reason for why you are using this feature.
>   Please provide instructions for how to reproduce this feature that are at least 20 characters.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. What don't you understand about it?

Comment: where to perform these operation i cant get. means i'm not getting any fields where i explain why and where need this feature and second option... too

Comment: There should be a large text box for that. See https://scontent-sin1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/t39.2178-6/12057211_1649027638670373_1865188832_n.png

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.